# How do I build an Asp.Net Core Razor page control that allows users to sign their names?

Tags: asp.net-core

I am building an Asp.Net Core web application using Razor.
The intended audience for this app will be using it on tablets.
Part of the application consists of several pages/forms that will require user signatures.
We could retrieve an image of a user's signature and display that on demand in the web page.

Is it possible to be more interactive and allow users to "sign" the form/page within the browser? Are there any 3rd party control libraries that would support this functionality?
I pretty sure this can be done on native applications, but can I achieve this through Asp.Net Core?

Comment: Does this article [Create backend services for native mobile apps with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mobile/native-mobile-backend?view=aspnetcore-5.0) useful to you ?

Comment: @JasonPan - Unless I'm missing something, this is not addressing question. I know how to make backend Asp.Net Core service. I'm not building a native app. I'm building an Asp.Net Core app using Razor. The question is how to incorporate control in webpage for user signatures. Is a <Canvas> something I can use?

Answer (score 2):

I found [signature_pad](https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad) in github, and it works for me.

**You can take a look at the screenshots of my test steps first, and I will add the test code at the bottom.**

[image]

[image]

[image]

## Test Code

*1. signature.cshtml*

```
@*
    For more information on enabling MVC for empty projects, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860
*@
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/signature_pad@2.3.2/dist/signature_pad.min.js"></script>

<form method="POST">
    <p>
        <canvas width="500" height="400" id="signature"
            style="border:1px solid black"></canvas><br>
        <button type="button" id="accept"
            class="btn btn-primary">
            Accept signature
        </button>
        <button type="submit" id="save"
            class="btn btn-primary">
            Save
        </button><br>
        <img width="500" height="400" id="savetarget"
         style="border:1px solid black"><br>
        <input id="SignatureDataUrl" type="text">
    </p>
</form>
<script>
    $(function () {
        var canvas = document.querySelector('#signature');
        var pad = new SignaturePad(canvas);
        $('#accept').click(function () {
            var data = pad.toDataURL();
            $('#savetarget').attr('src', data);
            $('#SignatureDataUrl').val(data);
            pad.off();
        });
        $('#save').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/ForTest/get_signature",
                type: "POST",
                data: { base64png:$('#SignatureDataUrl').val()},
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log("success");
                },
                error: function (hata, ajaxoptions, throwerror) {
                    alert("failed");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

*2. C# code*

```
[HttpPost]
public string get_signature(string base64png) {
    var dataUri = base64png;//"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K...";
    var encodedImage = dataUri.Split(',')[1];
    var decodedImage = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedImage);
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("signature_pic/"+DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")+"signature.png", decodedImage);
    return "ok";
}
```

**Tips**

If you want test my code, you need create signature_pic folder like me.